# How to deploy a pinax django project to iis via Helicon Zoo?

Tags: django, iis, pinax, helicontech

Today I found a simple way to deploy django projects to iis using Helicon Zoo tool, see

- http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/
- http://www.helicontech.com/articles/running-django-on-windows-with-performance-tests/

I tested some projects of django, such as osqa, and some others. I test to deploy a project made from pinax *zero* template, it works good. But when I test to deploy a project made from pinax *basic* template it not works. An error page shown to me:

> Unhandled Exception
>
> An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

Can some body help me, because I hope to develop an django project from the pinax *basic* template and plain to deply it on an IIS server. Thanks!

My develop machine is: windows 7, iis 7.5, python 2.7, django 1.31, pinax 0.9a2.

Comment: I worked for a day again, now the answer is found. Very easy, there is a folder named apps in the basic project, put it in python_path via editing file *web.config*, it is all. haha...

Comment: I can't get that working with Django ... can you provide more details ?